# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception in main method

Tags: java

I am getting array bound error but to my mind, array starts from 0, so what is wrong with this code?

```
public class Quadratic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double b = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double c = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);

        double discriminant = b*b - 4.0*c;
        double sqroot = Math.sqrt(discriminant);

        double root1 = (-b + sqroot)/ 2.0;
        double root2 = (-b - sqroot)/ 2.0;

        System.out.println(root1);
        System.out.println(root2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you passing two strings to your program ? How do you launch it ?

Comment: My goal is to ask the user to input b and c and then let the computer to solve the equation for the roots...

Answer (score 2):

Protect yourself: be defensive.

```
    public class Quadratic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length> 1) {
            double b = ((args.length > 0) ? Double.parseDouble(args[0]) : 0.0);
            double c = ((args.length > 1) ? Double.parseDouble(args[1]) : 0.0);

            double discriminant = b*b - 4.0*c;
            double sqroot = Math.sqrt(discriminant);

            double root1 = (-b + sqroot)/ 2.0;
            double root2 = (-b - sqroot)/ 2.0;

            System.out.println(root1);
            System.out.println(root2);
        } else {
            System.out.println("two arguments are required: b and c, please");
        }
    }
}
```

What happens if the discriminant is negative?  What if it's zero?

Why are you restricting yourself to the case where a = 1?

Comment: Okay, I understand length check, but what does 0.0 mean? I tried to change it to 5.0 or anything else and I receive "NaN" in the console

Comment: Please read the code and study a bit of Java.  It's the ternary operator: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html.  If the predicate is true, it returns the first argument; if not, it returns the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an item in args[0] and/or args[1]. You need to check that there are enough arguments in the array.

```
double b = args.length>=1?Double.parseDouble(args[0]):0.0;
double c = args.length>=2?Double.parseDouble(args[1]):0.0;
```

If there are no arguments in the array, then it means that you didn't pass an argument into the program or you didn't pass enough arguments.

Comment: @Mat I'm not suggesting how the OP should handle the situation, I'm just providing an example of how to avoid the exception. The logical consistency of the program is entirely up to the OP to ensure.

Comment: I'll argue that your explanation doesn't match your code. You say "You need to check that there are enough args", your code doesn't do that. It checks whether there is exactly one argument, then if there are exactly two.

Comment: @Mat Ah, I got it... >= is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try and debug it. print the size of args using `System.out.println(args.length);`.
if the size is smaller then 2 your not getting the parameters to your main class.

Comment: I received 0.0 after checking as you said. What would that mean? My array is empty?

Answer (score -1):

[ArrayIndexOutOfBounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) exception occur when you are trying to extract the variable at a wrong position in the array.

When you run a program in java after compilation e.x.`javac hello` and then executing the class file by `java hello` , the 0th position of the `args[0]` will be the filename i.e. `hello` in this case.

For you to successfully extract argument issued at the run time you have to use n+1 position in the array. For example. If I am running my program as `java hello argument` I'll be using `args[1]` if I wish to use the issued variable `argument` at run time and so on for extracting the associated text.

If you are unsure whether your statement will generate an exception or not, it is always safe to use `try & catch` block .Read - [Exception Handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: Not in Java. `args[0]` is the first argument, not the executable name.